# Asynchronous communication with Android(client) and Node.js(server)

Tags: android, node.js, cross-domain

I want a communication with Android and Node.js.

I implemented program and it goes well when they are on the same Network(I mean same WIFI). But when I disconnect my android phone from wifi and connect to mobile data, then communication is unable. After I searched, I found that the cross-domain problem exists.
But I can't find the solution that fits in my situation.
Please can you help me to solve this problem?

Here is my server-side code(server.js).

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var port = 9000;
var cors = require('cors');

var welcome = "new msg from server!";

app.get('/get', function(req, res) {
    console.log('>> send new msg to client...');
    res.json(welcome);
})
app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    console.log('<< receive new msg from client...');
    var info_from_client;
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        info_from_client = JSON.parse(data);
    })
    req.on('end', function(data) {
        var log_temp = "contents : \nname = " + info_from_client.user_name +          "\nfinger_print = " + info_from_client.finger_print;
    console.log(log_temp);
    res.write(log_temp);
    res.end();
    })
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('now server is starting...');
})
```

And here is my client-side code.

```
public class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private TextView tv;
private int action;
private int get = 1;
private int post = 2;


public SendToServer (TextView tv, int action) {
    this.tv = tv;
    this.action = action;
}

public String get_action(HttpURLConnection connection) {

    InputStream stream;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer buffer;

    try {
        connection.connect();

        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {

            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of finally

    return null;

}
public String post_action(HttpURLConnection connection) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.accumulate("user_name", "Na Jun Yeop");
        jsonObject.accumulate("finger_print", "12388452218");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    OutputStream outputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer buffer;

    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {

            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of finally

    return null;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        if (action == get) {
            return get_action(connection);
        }
        else if (action == post) {
            return post_action(connection);
        }

        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();


    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {

            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of finally


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tv.setText(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, you will need to put your Node.js server live with SSL certificate or secure https. For local testing, you should only try with same local network.
Try updating following parameters in your request and see if it works

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and is there any way to solve it by using jsonp or proxy??